# Can you report cheaters on online Mario Kart Wii

Tags: mario-kart-wii

It seems like the number of annoying cheater on online Mario Kart Wii is increasing. Yesterday I had to reconnect three times before I was put in a group with normal people. Is there any way I can report the usernames or something to Nintendo so that they can do something about it?

Comment: how where they cheating? I have never seen this!

Comment: They're getting unlimited powerups and sometimes win without racing. If someone in the group has over 9500 points that's usually a good hint that it is not going to be a fun game...

Comment: wow. I assume they are playing on a modded game/console. how pointless.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake Why would you not want to dominate the leaderboards of a game geared towards 15 year olds by cheating? Sounds like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Instructions

1. Identify cheaters early on in the game, if possible. Cheaters often have absurd win and loss records, i.e. 100 wins and no losses. They usually will have hacked the game to give them use of unlimited items. For example, if you are hit with a blue shell early in the race and no one has had time to even reach the first item box, you're probably dealing with a cheater.
2. Quit out of matches against cheaters. If you're able to identify a cheater before the match starts by looking at his win/loss record, then quit out before the match starts. If you quit out before the match starts you won't receive a loss. If the match has already started, quit out anyway. Attempting to race against cheaters at all rewards their behavior.
3. Report the problem to Nintendo. Although there isn't any official way to deal with cheating in Mario Kart, i.e. by banning the hackers, the Nintendo Tech Support Forum suggests that you fill out an online customer service form so Nintendo can investigate. Fill out all the pertinent information that you can remember about the match such as method of cheating and the player's name. A link to the form is available in the Resources section.

[Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_6941358_report-_mario-kart_-wii-wfc.html)

And [HERE](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/webform.jsp) is a link for a Nintento form.

Comment: You can't see opponents' win/loss ratios in MKWii, only VR/BR.

Comment: This sounds like an okay plan.. I was looking for a more constructive solution, but since there apparently is none, I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Wow reading this makes me think Nintendo is still way behind in terms of online gaming. I just don't understand how this can happen on any closed proprietary hardware platform. It's not like this is PC Gaming.

Comment: Go to the [CHAT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) best way to talk about it. But, I love Nintendo, but ... They make a good game and drain it so much... (no, they didn't only one game, but the meaning is that they focus on the main games without new ones). It's almost the same thing over and over again. better graphics, "new story", same idea, same characters (maybe one or two new). Microsoft and Sony are WAY ahead in all those factors and they have great titles too.

Answer (score 0):

Nintendo is normally good at keeping it's online free of hackers. If the problem persists I suggest contacting Nintendo's customer support.